# Samsung UMPC, Built in Camera doesn't support DirectX how can I use it?

Tags: .net, directx, camera

The Samsung Q1 Ultra, is the perfect device for my software except that the built in camera seems to be incompatible with standard DirectX drivers, so my .Net camera implementation can't use the device. I have limited experience in this area..

Even Skype can't access this camera, but a little program from Samsung can.. I've looked at the program's assemblies and it's too obfuscated to see inside so I can't see anyway to use them..

What sort of camera could this be? Are there any .Net classes / implementations I can use to access this camera?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into DX. Does DX do webcam now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that certain Samsung Q1 Ultra's built in cameras do work with standard DirectX drivers. Therefore a standard .net implementation that works with most usb web cams will be sufficient.

We found that a couple of devices we had must have been older models where this isn't the case. But recently some of the Samsungs we've got hold of the camera works straight away so Samsung must have fixed the issue..